# How do I inject data from the server into a Vue CLI app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-render-function

I have a Vue CLI app that I want to connect to a server back-end.
The server will return a view template with a data payload, and I want to inject that payload as JSON into the Vue app as a data property.

The `index.html` file generated by Vue CLI looks like the following (I set `filenameHashing` to `false` in `vue.config.js` to avoid random file names):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8>
        <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link href=/css/app.css rel=preload as=style>
        <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.css rel=preload as=style>
        <link href=/js/app.js rel=preload as=script>
        <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.js rel=preload as=script>
        <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.css rel=stylesheet>
        <link href=/css/app.css rel=stylesheet>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=app>
        </div>
        <script src=/js/chunk-vendors.js></script>
        <script src=/js/app.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And `main.js` looks like the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import SiteContainer from './components/layout/SiteContainer.vue';

new Vue({
    render: h => h(SiteContainer)
}).$mount('#app');
```

I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
<div id="app" :data="{{ json-string-of-data-payload-from-server }}">
```

So that I can then access the data in `SiteContainer` as follows:

```
props: [
    'data'
]
```

I've tried essentially doing what I wrote above, but because the `render` method seems to completely replace the `#app` div with the `site-container` component, the `:data` property is lost as well.

I also saw that you can pass a second argument to `render` with data, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work, and ultimately, that's in `main.js`, not the view template file that the server will use, which is where I need the JSON data to be to get it from the server to the Vue app.

How can I pass data from the server-generated view template to the Vue CLI app to get everything going? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out.

By defining the `SiteContainer` component as a Vue.js component in `main.js` first, I am able to freely use the component in the HTML file to get what I want.

Specifically, I changed the `main.js` file as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import SiteContainer from './components/SiteContainer.vue';

Vue.component('SiteContainer', SiteContainer); // This is the key.

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

And then the `body` part of the HTML file becomes the following (i.e., replace the `#app` `div` that I had in my question above):

```
<SiteContainer id="app" :data="{{ json-string-of-data-payload-from-server }}">
</SiteContainer>
```